# For loop not working properly when trying to remove lines from a file

Tags: file, for-loop

I am doing an exercise in Python which consists in programming a program that blocks some sites at specific hours by adding or suppressing the sites lists from the host file. The program works at a tick of 5 seconds. The blocking part works properly, but when i want to unblock the sites it needs more than a tick to unblock the sites.

Here's the code:

```
import time
hosts_path=r"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"
hosts_temp="hosts"
redirect="127.0.0.1"
website_list=["www.facebook.com","www.gmail.com",r"https://mail.google.com/","https://www.youtube.com/","https://www.helsebiblioteket.no/om-oss/english?emneside=true"]



while True:
    if 2200 >= int(time.strftime("%H%M")) >= 2100:
        print("a")
        with open(hosts_path,'r+') as hosts:
            content=hosts.read()
            for website in website_list:
                if website in content:
                    pass
                else:
                    hosts.write('\n'+redirect+ ' '+ website+ '\n')
    **else:
        print('b')
        with open(hosts_path,'r+') as hosts:
            lines=hosts.readlines()
            hosts.seek(0)
            for l in lines:
                if  "#" not in l:
                    del lines[lines.index(l)]
                
        with open(hosts_path,'w') as hosts:
            for line in lines:
                hosts.write(line)**
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

In bold is the part of the code with the problem. the program overwrites the files without completing all the loop. For example i have three sites i want to delete. After 1 tick it deletes only 1 site.